# How do I insert a new record into an Access Database with an autonumber field using OleDb in C#

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio, ms-access, oledb

I am trying to implement a database in one of my project. The table thats giving me a problem is structured as follows.

```
Table Savegame: 
SaveID(autonumber),
Username(Long text),
GameTitle(long text),
Savestate(short number)
```

I am trying to insert into the table using the following code

```
cmd.CommantText - "INSERT INTO Savegame(Username,GameTitle,Savestate) Values('"+username+"','"+game+"','1')";
```

Everytime I run the code I'm told that I cannot leave the SaveID field empty since its NOT NULL.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Much as I have a loathing for MSaccess as a product.. Have you tried supplying a number, such as 0.. and seeing if it auto generates a number but the query is run because you supplied a value?

Answer (score 0):

At least, supply a number for *SaveState*:

```
cmd.CommantText - "INSERT INTO Savegame(Username,GameTitle,Savestate) Values('"+username+"','"+game+"',1)";
```

Also, are you sure, that the other fields are Long Text, not Short Text?